# How to replace NaN with a value which is meant to increase by 10 of previous non Non value?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame with some NaNs:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])
>>> df

0   1   2   3
1   4 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN   9

The result should be like this which is just +10 of the previous NaN value of the column.

      
   0  1  2  3
   1  4  12 13
   2  14  12  9
```

Is there any way to do this using any methods?or do I have to iterate each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill the `NaN`s with the previous non-NaN value, and then a simple mask to increment all by 10:

```py
result = df.ffill()
result[df.isna()] += 10
```

Output

```
      0     1     2
0   1.0   2.0   3.0
1   4.0  12.0  13.0
2  14.0  12.0   9.0
```

Comment: It displays an error like this/TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

Comment: @AravindP really? maybe it's a version thing? I ran it on my machine and it worked just fine. here's a repl.it that runs it just fine : https://repl.it/repls/FortunateBurlyChapters#main.py